# Role-based authorization for AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-identity, amazon-cognito

Thanks to newly released [module](https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider); AWS Cognito is now an ASP.NET Core Identity Provider.

It would be nice to do role based authorization via `[Authorize(Roles= "{Role}")]`; however currently it doesn't work; in part probably because cognito (groups/roles) are mapped to `cognito:groups` claim.

Is there a way to get it to work?
(besides writing a custom policy)

have also submitted an issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider/issues/86

Other references:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-asp-net-core-identity-provider-preview-for-amazon-cognito/

Comment: Luckily on github this question had better reception; here is a good solution that was suggested:
https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider/issues/86#issuecomment-685934362

p.s. am quite confused about why the question was closed ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is old however I just managed to get this working without a custom Authoriser.

My page class is defined with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class MyClass : PageModel
{
...
}
```

The case of "admin" appears to be important (had a similar issue with the logout URL - found it had to be lower case).  Initially I had it as "Admin" and it didn't work.

In your "startup.cs" file, where you are setting the "TokenValidationParameters" you set a "RoleClaimType".

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
  ValidateIssuer = authOptions.Value.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer,
  RoleClaimType = "cognito:groups"
};
```